# SQL - Join two tables, creating multiple columns with custom outputs from the result of the query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I've got two tables.
The relevant columns from Table 1 look like:

```
[DateField ][H0][H1]...[H23]
 2014-09-01  2   4      2
 2014-09-02  3   1      4
 ...
 2014-09-30  3   3      2
```

The relevant columns of Table 2 look like:

```
[DateField ][Start][End][T-Val][Status]
 2014-09-01  0      4    1      Off
 2014-09-01  5      18   2      Low
 2014-09-01  19     23   1      Off
 2014-09-02  0      10   1      Off
 2014-09-02  11     20   2      Med
 2014-09-02  21     23   1      Off
 ...
```

I need to get an output like...

```
[DateField ][H0][H1]...[H23][H0TST][H1TST]...[H12TST]...[H23TST]
 2014-09-01  2   4      2    1_Off  1_Off     2_Low      1_Off
 2014-09-02  3   1      4    1_Off  1_Off     2_Med      1_Off
 ...
```

Where an additional 24 columns are made, each with the T-Val and the Status values in the column based on the Start and End values that correspond with a single date.

The T-Val and Status fields are dependent on the Start and End fields, such that H0TST will gather the T-Value and Status based on the 0 in H0TST, depending on which Start and End range row it falls under.

After joining the two tables on the DateField column, how should I go about structuring the rest of the query?

Please help point me in the right direction, thanks!

Comment: I don't think this will work, given your table structure. If you're only joining on Date, how will your extra fields know which `T-Val` and `Status` to use from `Table2`?

Comment: i would use select with join and case condition that will return concat your expected value

Comment: Use "CASE WHEN .... ELSE '' END"  expressions to create the 24 columns you need. You will also need to GROUP BY date and only keep the MAX() of each such column

Comment: Got it. Starting out with @jpw's suggestion got me the desired results. Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a aggregated case expression would give you what you want:

```
select t1.*, 
    h0tst  = max(case when t1.H0  between t2.start and t2.[end] then concat([T-Val],'-', status) end),
    h1tst  = max(case when t1.H1  between t2.start and t2.[end] then concat([T-Val],'-', status) end),
    h23tst = max(case when t1.H23 between t2.start and t2.[end] then concat([T-Val],'-', status) end )
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.DateField = t2.DateField
group by t1.DateField, t1.H0, t1.H1, t1.h23
```

This would produce an output like:

```
DateField   H0  H1  H23 h0tst   h1tst   h23tst
2014-09-01  2   4   2   1-Off   1-Off   1-Off
2014-09-02  3   1   4   1-Off   1-Off   1-Off
```

Comment: @shawnt00 With SQL Server (and most other databases) you need to group all columns in the select list that are not part of aggregate functions. It would have worked with MySQL though as that database does some magic stuff that are non-standard.